# Printing to console and raw_input at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, raw-input

I have a client.py and a server.py.  The client receives occasional messages from the server.  The client can also send messages to the server.

Because raw_input appears to block the main thread, when the client receives a message from the server, it can't print to the console, and requires raw_input to finish first.

I've tried to use multithreading to get around this, but in the following code, the raw_input doesn't even get called.  The following is client.py

```
import socket
import sys
import threading

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

def listen_for_server_response(s):
    while 1:
        data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print(data)

def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])))
    thread = threading.Thread(target = listen_for_server_response(s))
    thread.start()
    while 1:
        command = raw_input("Command: ")
        s.send(command)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems like bad design but you need to call threading with a callable function

```
thread = threading.Thread(target = listen_for_server_response,args=(s,))
thread.start()
```

by calling it like you do in the example you are calling it before the thread starts and just looping forever ... you dont even make it to thread.start

Comment: If you think it's poorly designed, I'm happy to try another way. What do you suggest?

Comment: you should be using curses probably (if you insist on a terminal) or use a proper gui ...

Comment: +1 but I'd argue against the "bad design" part. If your goal is just to echo to the screen this is okay (IMHO).